# All Buttons with Intent Don't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-intent

Goal:
When I press one of the buttons, you should be referred into a next intent page.

Problem:
It only works for button named "Activity 1" but not the remaining buttons although you use the same source code for button "Activity 1", "Activity 2" and  "Activity 3".

What part am I missing?

Thank you!

Info:
*I'm new in android
*I'm using API 23

---

androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfdimarzio.application">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".firstactivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity2">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

MainActivity.java

```
package com.jfdimarzio.application;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.attr.value;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent != null)
        {
            String valuee = intent.getStringExtra("key");

            if(valuee != null)
            {
                final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvw_activity1);

                textViewToChange.setText(valuee);
            }
        }
    }


    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btn_activity1:
                Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), firstactivity.class );
                myIntent1.putExtra("key", "Hello! Activity 1");
                startActivity(myIntent1);
                break;

            case R.id.btn_activity2:
                Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class );
                myIntent2.putExtra("key", "Hello! Activity 2");
                startActivity(myIntent2);
                break;

            case R.id.btn_activity3:
                Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity3.class );
                myIntent3.putExtra("key", "Hello! Activity 3");
                startActivity(myIntent3);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

---

firstactivity.java

```
package com.jfdimarzio.application;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class firstactivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String valuee = intent.getStringExtra("key");

        final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvw_activity1);

        textViewToChange.setText(valuee);
    }
}
```

---

Activity3.java

```
package com.jfdimarzio.application;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Activity3 extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String valuee = intent.getStringExtra("key");

        final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvw_activity1);

        textViewToChange.setText(valuee);
    }

}
```

---

Activity2.java

```
package com.jfdimarzio.application;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity2 extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String valuee = intent.getStringExtra("key");

        final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvw_activity1);

        textViewToChange.setText(valuee);
    }

}
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jfdimarzio.application.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvw_activity1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_activity1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtvw_first"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Activity 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_activity2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_activity1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Activity 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_activity3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_activity2"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Activity 3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

firstactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txt_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvw_activity1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

activity2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to declare all the activities in your Manifest XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not declared all the activities in your `Manifest` File. Make sure you include all the activities in your `Manifest.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jfdimarzio.application">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".firstactivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity2">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity3">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to declare all the activites in the manifest file and name of the file in the 
`<activity android:name="...."></activity>` tag must to similar to the name of your .java class file name.
Your entry of Activity2.java class is

```
<activity android:name=".activity2">
</activity>
```

It should be like this

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2">
</activity>
```